# Are we able to remove tax when editing order

Tags: orders, tax

I would like to be able to remove country-based tax from specific orders for customers if they show proof that the orders are for export. However, it seems like I am unable to remove the tax when editing orders.

Answer (score 2):

How about just creating a credit memo for the amount attributable to tax.  You are after all effectively giving a partial refund.